# Url not accessible

Tags: product, 404, index

I've added a product on my magento 2.2.4 website.

But when I go to my product, I have this message (a 404 page in the console)

> L'URL que vous demandez n'est pas accessible.

But it's only on one on my product, all of my other products work well.

First I had this message, then I tried to change the url manually.

How to fix this ? Tried to reindex, clear/flush cache

UPDATE

I've tried to rewrites the url, but it looks like the word "perl" breaks it. Anywhere I put this word, the page is broken. Without it, it works...

Answer (score 0):

First delete this product then recreate this product to check if it fix the issue.